# como insertar en mysql con un foreach

Tags: php, php7, php5

tengo un problema en un formulario tengo una lista bastante extensa de personas que algunas veces pueden ser 2,10,15,100 según la base de datos y como se filtren

el problema radica que para traer esas personas dentro del while  a la par traigo un select estático de la siguiente manera:

```
    <?php

                                  while ($estadoacta = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                                      <tr>
                                           <td>
                                              <label for="">
                                                  <?php echo $estadoacta['nombres']; ?>
                                               </label>
                                           </td>
                                           <td>
                                               <div class="form-group">
                                                   <select class="form-control" name="asistencia[]" id="<?php echo $estadoacta['id_persona']; ?>">
                                                      <option value="0">-- Selecione un Estado --</option>
                                                      <option value="1">Asistio</option>
                                                      <option value="2">inasistencia</option>
                                                      <option value="3">Excusa</option>
                                                  </select>
                                              </div>
                                         </td>
    
                                       </tr>
<?php  }  ?>
```

en el select el value significa:
1.- asistio
2.- inasistencia
3.- excusa
SEGUN la BBDD

UN EJEMPLO filtre solo dos personas...
a una le pongo asistió y al otro inasistencia que en realidad seria.. 1 y 2
en el `POST` se envian asi:

```
asistencia: (2) ["1", "2"]
```

que en teoría debería ser así el problema es, y aquí es mi pregunta que al momento de insertarlo a la base de datos me los inserta pero.. los dos los inserta con el ultimo valor que seleccione

por ejemplo: seleccione 6 personas y le pongo su asistencia 1,1,1,2,1,3 todos me los inserta con un 3!!! osea el ultimo valor

al momento de insertarlos a la BBDD lo hago asi:

```
foreach ($asistencia as $estado) {
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE tbl_participantes SET id_estado_participante=? WHERE id_reunion=?");
            $stmt->bind_param("ii", $estado, $id_reunion);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
```

estructura de la tabla :tbl_participantes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se que puede ser, si alguien me puede sacar de mi error se lo agradecería

Comment: Incluye la estructura de `tbl_participantes`.

Comment: listo! ya la añadie en forma de imagen no la tengo en codigo

Comment: En el arreglo `$asistencia` ¿Cómo sabes a qué  `id_persona` o `id_participante` le corresponde cada valor?

Comment: como lo soluciono, como le asigno ese id_persona

Comment: con un input "hidden" logre enviar el ID de las personas pero no se como meter ese ARRAY al arreglo $asistencia similar al de asistencia se envia asi : participante: (2) ["116", "159"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manda `id_persona` en el nombre del `select`, en un arreglo `asistencia[id_persona>]=id_estado_participante`:

```
<select class="form-control" name="asistencia[<?php echo $estadoacta['id_persona'] ?>]">
```

Para después obtener la persona en la clave del arreglo:

```
foreach( $_REQUEST['asistencia'] as $id_persona => $id_estado_participante ){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare( "UPDATE tbl_participantes 
                                 SET id_estado_participante=? 
                                 WHERE id_reunion=?
                                   AND id_persona=?
                              "
                            );
    $stmt->bind_param( "iii"
                     , $id_estado_participante
                     , $id_reunion
                     , $id_persona
                     );
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: que crack! mucha gracias!!!